# Applying background color to nested sub-group header when active

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

### Plain English Question

I have a nested v-list that looks like this:

[image]

The goal is to have the headers `"BusinessUnitA"` and `"TaskY"` be highlighetd (some background color) **when active**. Currently they will only be highlighted if I hover over them. `"Task Y"` is in red font if it is active, but I need it to be highlighted.

### Code

This is the corresponding html template:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-list dense>
      <v-list-group
          v-for="businessUnit in businessUnits"
          :key="businessUnit.businessUnitName"
          v-model="businessUnit.active"
          no-action
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content >
            <v-list-item-title   v-text="businessUnit.businessUnitName"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
        <v-list-group
            v-for="item in businessUnit.tasks"
            :key="item.taskName"
            :value="true"
            no-action
            sub-group
        >
          <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.taskName"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>
          <v-list-item-group>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col
                      class="d-flex"
                      cols="6"
                      sm="6"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-avatar>
                      <v-img :src='item.responsible.avatar'></v-img>
                    </v-list-item-avatar>

                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title class="mb-2" v-text="item.responsible.name"></v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.responsible.phone"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.responsible.email"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                      class="d-flex"
                      cols="6"
                      sm="6"
                  >
                    <v-list-item-avatar>
                      <v-img :src="item.deputy.avatar"></v-img>
                    </v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title class="mb-2" v-text="item.deputy.name + ' (Stv.)'"></v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.deputy.phone"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.deputy.email"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                      class="d-flex"
                  cols="12">
                  <v-divider></v-divider>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

And the script part:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ZklListNew",
  data: () => ({
        businessUnits: [
          {
            businessUnitName: 'BusinessUnit A',
            municipality: 'Cityname',
            tasks:
                [
                  {
                    taskName: 'Task Y',
                    responsible: {
                      name: 'Max Müller',
                      email: 'max.müller@test.mail.ch',
                      phone: '+44 77 123 45 67',
                      avatar: require("@/assets/avatar-placeholder.gif"),
                    },
                    deputy: {
                      name: 'Katharina Knüller',
                      email: 'katharina.knüller@test.mail.ch',
                      phone: '+44 77 123 45 67',
                      avatar: require("@/assets/avatar-placeholder.gif"),
                    }
                  }]
          },
        ]
      }
  ),
}
</script>
```

### What I have tried

I tried using active class (according to the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/#examples) in the following way:

template:

```
...

<template v-slot:activator>
  <v-list-item>
  <v-list-item-content >
    <v-list-item-title  active-class="border" v-text="businessUnit.businessUnitName"></v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</template>

...

<template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title active-class="border" v-text="item.taskName"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>
...
```

And for the style:

```
<style scoped>
.border {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

I also tried to add custom classes like `class="v-list-group__header"` and applied a styling to it but with no effect.

*Sorry for the long question. I try to write as concise as possible and as detailed as necessary.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're so close! If I understand you question correctly, all you need to do is add the `active-class` prop to your `v-list-group`. This will apply whatever class you assign to it, only when the item is active. In your case, make sure to add it to each list group.

```
<v-list-group
  v-for="businessUnit in businessUnits"
  :key="businessUnit.businessUnitName"
  v-model="businessUnit.active"
  no-action
  active-class="grey lighten-2"
>
```

check out the active-class section [here in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/#props-active-class)